# I am unable to login after installing ubuntu 14.04 even my password is correct

Tags: login

I installed ubuntu 32 bit on Vmware player ,it was installed well and it is showing myubuntu and guest login GUI when opened . I can login through guest but I am unable to login through myubuntu

Comment: Does the guest system have the right keyboard layout configured?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Keep in mind that your password is case sensitive. This may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you boot to your Linux system, select "Advanced Options", and then elect the recovery method.

From here, select root which will then bring you to shell. Now that you've selected tha, enter the following:

> mount -o rw, remount /

Once there, you should then be able to update your password with the following command:

> sudo passwd [your username]

This will then ask for your new Unix Password and to repeat. You can perform the same steps for root also.

You want find many tutorials online (YouTube) on how to perform this also. I note that this answer has already been posted, with a faster method, apologizes.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Restart in recovery mode, an choose for "drop to root shell prompt"
 Then type  "passwd myubuntu"

The system will you ask for a new password (twice). 
type "exit" and then 
  Restart ubuntu